# LibreOffice Calc: Formula needed to find all cells of certain value in table

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc

Let's say my first table looks like this:

| r/c | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | o | c |
| 2 |  | x |  |
| 3 | o | x |  |

I want a second table, within the first document, that looks like that:

| r/c | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Occurences of "x" | A1 | B2 | B3 |
| 2 | Occurences of "o" | A3 | B1 |  |
| 3 | Occurences of "c" | C1 |  |  |

Is there an elegant way to do this using formulas?
I know I will always have to specify a maximum number of occurences and reserve that many cells in a row of the second table.

I already managed to put together some formulas for table 2:

```
B1 = =IF(NOT(ISNA(MATCH("x";$Table1.$A$1:$Table1.$A$3;0)));CONCATENATE("A";MATCH("x";$Table1.$A$1:$Table1.$A$3;0));IF(NOT(ISNA(MATCH("x";$Table1.$B$1:$Table1.$B$3;0)));CONCATENATE("B";MATCH("x";$Table1.$B$1:$Table1.$B$3;0));IF(NOT(ISNA(MATCH("x";$Table1.$C$1:$Table1.$C$3;0)));CONCATENATE("C";MATCH("x";$Table1.$C$1:$Table1.$C$3;0)))))

B2 = =IF(NOT(ISNA(MATCH("o";$Table1.$A$1:$Table1.$A$3;0)));CONCATENATE("A";MATCH("o";$Table1.$A$1:$Table1.$A$3;0));IF(NOT(ISNA(MATCH("o";$Table1.$B$1:$Table1.$B$3;0)));CONCATENATE("B";MATCH("o";$Table1.$B$1:$Table1.$B$3;0));IF(NOT(ISNA(MATCH("o";$Table1.$C$1:$Table1.$C$3;0)));CONCATENATE("C";MATCH("o";$Table1.$C$1:$Table1.$C$3;0)))))

B3 = =IF(NOT(ISNA(MATCH("c";$Table1.$A$1:$Table1.$A$3;0)));CONCATENATE("A";MATCH("c";$Table1.$A$1:$Table1.$A$3;0));IF(NOT(ISNA(MATCH("c";$Table1.$B$1:$Table1.$B$3;0)));CONCATENATE("B";MATCH("c";$Table1.$B$1:$Table1.$B$3;0));IF(NOT(ISNA(MATCH("c";$Table1.$C$1:$Table1.$C$3;0)));CONCATENATE("C";MATCH("c";$Table1.$C$1:$Table1.$C$3;0)))))
```

I am sure I could work out something similar for the rest, but these formulas are getting huge and are going to drive me insane in case I ever need to change something, so I was wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing this.

Edit:
Alternativley, it would also be nice to have table2 look like this, if it is easier to implement:

| r/c | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Occurences of "x" | A1,B2,B3 |
| 2 | Occurences of "o" | A3,B1 |
| 3 | Occurences of "c" | C1 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, make it easier for yourself and Calc - remove the words "Occurences of" from the cell, leave only the desired value (x, o, c, etc.). If you need this word for beauty, you can show it in a cell using a custom format `Occurences of \"@\"`

Now compare all the cells in the original range with the value in the first column. If the value does not match, then use an empty string. Otherwise, use the ADDRESS() function to get the coordinates of the cell. Combine the results with TEXTJOIN() and don't forget that this is an array formula, complete the formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

```
{=TEXTJOIN(",";1;IF(Sheet1.$A$1:$C$3=$A1;ADDRESS(ROW(Sheet1.$A$1:$C$3);COLUMN(Sheet1.$A$1:$C$3);4;1);""))}
```

[image: Result]